# How to implement a "package-global config object"?

Tags: matlab

I want to implement a "package-global config object" encapsulating configuration *parameters* to be shared by a suite of scripts and functions of a package.

*Ideally*, I would like to be able to use this object like this:

```
import mypkg.config;

% ...
% config parameters should be settable at run-time
config.start_time = clock();

% ...
% ideally, it should be possible to apply subscript subexpressions, such
% as {:} below, *directly* to config parameters
conn = database(config.connParams{:});
% here, config.connParams is expected to contain a cell array of strings
```

Needless to say, the names of parameters in `config` should be protected from shadowing by names defined outside of the package.

One additional important requirement for the config object is that it should be possible to initialize all its parameters entirely within a single file.

I don't know of any simple way to implement the utopian `config` illustrated above.  It seems that if `foo.bar` is imported with `import`, then `bar.baz` can only be either a function or a class, not a variable.  (But please, correct me if I'm wrong!)

I'm looking for ways to approximate a `config` object with the properties outlined above.

BTW, I realize that *read-only* parameters (*aka* "constants") can be simulated by "constant functions", but this is not an acceptable solution, since I need to be able to initialize and/or modify at least some of the parameters in `config` at run time.

Comment: I don't think you can do this exactly the way you're asking with the `config.thing = ...` syntax, because a quirk in Matlab's syntax prevents assigning to or through any static property. But you could get close with static getter/setter methods, or regular getter/setter methods on an object accessed through a `Constant` singleton instance. (Though the multi-argument syntax you'd like for `config.connParams{:}` wouldn't work.) Would that be close enough?